# Running a script on a specific date of every month azure

Tags: azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

I want to run a powershell script on the 28th of each month at 23:00 UTC using azure. I am exploring azure logic apps and function apps and would ideally like to use a combination but either one would work as well.

I have tried using TimerTrigger in function apps and my initial thought was that using CRON it would be straightforward and I came up with `0 0 23 28 * ? *`. But I just realised that the day parameter only accepts 0-6 for the 7 days of the week.

In logic apps, I could not find anything other than a frequency setter which would allow me to run it once a month but doesn't give control over time.

Can anyone please suggest a way around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure function use NCRONTAB  library , further more details you could refer to this doc:[NCRONTAB expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer?tabs=csharp#ncrontab-expressions). The cron format should be `{second} {minute} {hour} {day} {month} {day-of-week}`.

If you want to set the timer at 28th of each month at 23:00 UTC, you could try this cron expression:`0 0 23 28 * *`.

[image]

About logic app you are right, for now it only support the frequency schedule, it could not implement the detailed time schedule.

Comment: thanks! I was using the "In-portal" dev environment instead of vs code/editor and it kept on giving me an error. will change it now, on your and hari's recommendation

Answer (score 2):

It can be achieved using just `CRON` expressions in Azure Functions.

CRON Expression -  `00 23 28 * *`

#### Explanation:

[image]
[Reference](https://crontab.guru/#00_23_27_*_*)

#### Update 1 :

> Ignore the date. i wrote it as 27. You can just put it as 28

I created a function app to validate this as OP mentioned it is not working.
Here's the function runtime console with calculated dates.

[image]

This is what my code looks like

```
[FunctionName("TimeTrigger")]
        public static void Run([TimerTrigger("0 23 27 * *")]TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
        }
```

Comment: Invalid Cron Expression. Please consult the documentation to learn more. this is what i get when i try to put this in TimerTrigger schedule. I have the same expression as you in my post but it doesn't work with timertrigger in azure funtion apps

Comment: as mentioned in the original post. this is what days is for in azure timertrigger "For days, the numeric values are 0 to 6 where 0 starts with Sunday."

Comment: @omaticat it does work fine. Edited my answer to attach azure function runtime console calculation

Comment: I was using the in portal gui and the timer didn't accept my cron expression (almost identical to yours). Thanks for updating, I will use a written function like yours now.